# no gradlew in beam-release-2.16.0

Tags: apache-spark, apache-beam

i'm following the guide [beam spark runner](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/spark/) , but i can't find how to launch`./gradlew build`. There is no gradlew in `beam-release-2.16.0/`. So i installed gradle and run `gradle build` in root dir. But i got error as

```
* Where: Build file '/home/jovyan/beam-release-2.16.0/buildSrc/build.gradle' line: 32

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':buildSrc'.
> Could not find method content() for arguments [build_5yge7ru6ybndk8rv1kkefnd2y$_run_closure1$_closure6$_closure7@37c7dcf3] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.
```

the content of line 32:

```
maven {
    url "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/"
    content { includeGroup "io.spring.gradle" }
  }
```

i have no idea on how to build apache_beam, anyone who can offer some idea will be helpful, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `./gradlew` build tool is omitted if you downloaded from the official source code release for [licensing reasons](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-8187).  In my opinion, there's some assumptions in the beam spark runner guide that make it difficult to follow.

If you want to **build** new Beam artifacts, you're probably better off getting the source from the [github repository](https://github.com/apache/beam), where the `./gradlew` exists.

Of course, if you just want to **obtain** the Beam 2.16.0 artifacts, you're probably better served by the published maven or pypi artifacts.

If you have a specific reason for using `./gradlew` on Beam 2.16.0 code, you *still* might be better off using the github repository on the `v2.16.0` tag.

(For example, the guide describes running the JobService endpoint by running `./gradlew :runners:spark:job-server:runShadow`.  This service is used in a very specific way for running cross-language pipelines in Spark.  If you are using just Spark and the Beam Java SDK, the "Legacy" instructions in the guide will get you running without requiring the gradle wrapper.)

Comment: oh, i get it. i think the repository fit me in my condition. Appreciate it!

Comment: but i am kind of confused by your NOTE,= =. i'm going to try with the guide anyway.