# Building beam-2.29.0 from source fails with error: Unresolved reference: compile

Tags: gradle, apache-beam

I am trying to build Beam 2.29.0 from source but when I issue command "gradle build" from the top or sdk directories I get the error:

> - Where:
>   Build file '/Users/Josefa/dev/code/example/beam-2.29.0/buildSrc/build.gradle.kts' line: 38

- What went wrong:
  Script compilation errors:

  Line 38:   compile(gradleApi())
  ^ Unresolved reference: compile

  Line 39:   compile(localGroovy())
  ^ Unresolved reference: compile

  Line 40:   compile("com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:6.1.0")
  ^ Unresolved reference: compile

My environment is:

Mac OS: 20.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0

---

### Gradle 7.2

Kotlin:       1.5.21
Groovy:       3.0.8
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          11.0.10 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.10+8-LTS-162)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.16 x86_64

Comment: Which SDK are you trying to build? For Java it might be easier to build specific components (for example, ./gradlew :sdks:java:). For Python you can, (1) setup a virtualenv (2) "cd beam/sdks/python" (3) "python setup.py sdist".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I downloaded the source from the Apache Beam site. This version does not contain the gradlew that is needed to build the source. You need to go to their [github repo](https://github.com/apache/beam) and download the code from there. Then you can switch to the right release in my case:

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/beam.git
git checkout release-2.29.0
./gradlew :sdks:java:core:build
```

In my case I was interested in building the Java SDK only. I got this from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59028662/no-gradlew-in-beam-release-2-16-0).

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you use the `gradle` command instead of the provided `gradlew` script. Please try building using the `gradlew` script instead.

For example,

```
./gradlew :sdks:java:core:build
```

Comment: There is no gradlew on Beam distribution 2.29.0 or 2.32.0. There is one at learning/katas/java/gradlew which if I run it from that directory it builds the code from that directory. I copied to the top level and I run but I got an error